# Magento 1.9 change custom option value depending on stock number

Tags: magento, product, magento-1.9

I have custom code that determines if a custom code value exists and if it does to select this option over the default sort order option in the product config.

What I am wanting to do is further add logic that if the product sku starts with  "F" then it will show the default sort order value for that product.

The custom code is in this file..

app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

Here is the code in question

```
            // Set Default for the following cases:
            // Ring Size for Men = T, Women = M
            // Price for Custom Option is $0 and is the last, unless defaulted by Men or Women.
            // if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M' && $isFemale) {
            //     $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
            // }
            // else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'T' && $isMale) {
            //     $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
            // } 
            // else if ($_value->getPrice() == 0.0000 && $hasNoPrice && !$isFemale && !$isMale) {
            //     $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
            // } 

            if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M') {
               $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
            }
            else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'T') {
                $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
            } 
        }
```

This code is ok as is.. but what I am wanting to add to the statements is that if the Stock code starts with 'F' then assign the default value.

something like

`if ($sku_code == 'F') { 
                $select->setValue($configValue); 
            }`

where this will show the default sort order value for the option..

I just cant seem to get this working.

Any help coding this and you get instant kudos and good Karma!

cheers

**update** Here is full code from Select.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Product options text type block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Catalog
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select
    extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN
            || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
            $require = ($_option->getIsRequire()) ? ' required-entry' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
                ->setData(array(
                    'id' => 'select_'.$_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require.' product-custom-option'
                ));
            if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']');
                    // ->addOption('', $this->__('Please Select'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().'][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect'.$require.' product-custom-option');
            }

            // This is a very specific case for Ring Size
            // $isMale = $isFemale = $hasNoPrice = false;
            // foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            //     if ($_value->getTitle() == 'I' && $_value->getPrice() == 0.0000) {
            //         $isFemale = true;
            //     } 
            //     else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M' && $_value->getPrice() == 0.0000) {
            //         $isMale = true;
            //     }

            //     if ($_value->getPrice() == 0.0000) {
            //         $hasNoPrice = true;
            //     }
            // } 

            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
                    'is_percent'    => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice(($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'))
                ), false);
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                    array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false))
                );

                // Set Default for the following cases:
                // Ring Size for Men = T, Women = M
                // Price for Custom Option is $0 and is the last, unless defaulted by Men or Women.
                // if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M' && $isFemale) {
                //     $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                // }
                // else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'T' && $isMale) {
                //     $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                // } 
                // else if ($_value->getPrice() == 0.0000 && $hasNoPrice && !$isFemale && !$isMale) {
                //     $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                // }

                //not sure about this line

                if ($sku_code[0] == 'F') {
                    $select->setValue($configValue);
                }

                else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M') {
                   $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                }
                else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'T') {
                    $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                } 
            }

            if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            } 

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO
            || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
            ) {
            $selectHtml = '<ul id="options-'.$_option->getId().'-list" class="options-list">';
            $require = ($_option->getIsRequire()) ? ' validate-one-required-by-name' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<li><input type="radio" id="options_' . $_option->getId() . '" class="'
                            . $class . ' product-custom-option" name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"'
                            . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
                            . ' value="" checked="checked" /><span class="label"><label for="options_'
                            . $_option->getId() . '">' . $this->__('None') . '</label></span></li>';
                    }
                    break;
                case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(array(
                    'is_percent'    => ($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent')
                ));

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = (is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue)) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $selectHtml .= '<li>' . '<input type="' . $type . '" class="' . $class . ' ' . $require
                    . ' product-custom-option"'
                    . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
                    . ' name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']' . $arraySign . '" id="options_' . $_option->getId()
                    . '_' . $count . '" value="' . $htmlValue . '" ' . $checked . ' price="'
                    . $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) . '" />'
                    . '<span class="label"><label for="options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count . '">'
                    . $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '</label></span>';
                if ($_option->getIsRequire()) {
                    $selectHtml .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . '$(\'options_' . $_option->getId() . '_'
                    . $count . '\').advaiceContainer = \'options-' . $_option->getId() . '-container\';'
                    . '$(\'options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count
                    . '\').callbackFunction = \'validateOptionsCallback\';' . '</script>';
                }
                $selectHtml .= '</li>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</ul>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your full template file where you're trying to do this?

Comment: @giollianosulit have added code from Select.php.. This is where the defaults are being added. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I don't understand right but you want to see if the sku_code starts with "f"?

EDIT:

```
if ($sku_code == 'F') { 
    $select->setValue($configValue); 
}
```

Try:

```
if (strpos($sku_code, 'F') === 0) { 
    $select->setValue($configValue); 
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
if (substr($sku_code, 0, 1) === 'F') { $select->setValue($configValue); }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: yes correct.. want to see if starts with f and in that case show default value.  Your on the right track here and it does kind of work but it is now applying the default value for all sku codes. not just the ones starting with F..