# Magento 1.9 if SKU Code Equals... code example not working - help :D

Tags: php, magento-1.9, sku

I am trying to check if sku first character equals then show a custom option value.  here is the code

```
if (strpos($sku_code, 'F') == 0) { 
    $select->setValue($configValue); 
}
```

Using this code works in the desired effect that it changes the value of the custom option but unfortunately it changes the value for all sku's not just the ones starting with 'F'

Any thoughts? or examples of something I could try?

***UPdate***
Thanks for the help.. I tried your solution but having same effect. Just ignoring the statement
here is the code i am using.

```
if (strpos($sku_code, 'F') === 0) {
                    $select->setValue($configValue); 
                }
                else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M') {
                    $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                }
                else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'T') {
                    $select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strpos($sku_code, 'F')
```

will return **false** if the search string is not found. And in PHP, 0 is considered false. Therefore, the condition of yours will be evaluated to true! You can check the type of the return value too, like, `if(strpos($sku_code, 'F') === 0)` as this would also check the datatype.

Comment: I edited comments above.  Tried your solution with same effect.

Comment: any help with this would be grand! :D

Comment: The if/elseif conditions doesn't look right. Do you have a sample of data you are trying to check/update?

I am just assuming this is probably how the condition must look like:

`if (strpos($sku_code, 'F') === 0) {`
                    '$select->setValue($configValue); `
                '}
                'else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'M') {`
                    `$select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());  `
               ` }`
                `else if ($_value->getTitle() == 'T') {`
                    `$select->setValue($_value->getOptionTypeId());}`

Comment: I agree something is wrong but this did the same thing and now just skips first if and uses the M and T values if they exist in the attribute.

This has stumped me as the code looks good and should work.. It works fine in other uses.

You can see full code here.[link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474355?noredirect=1

Comment: Then, it means, $sku_code format is different. Can you share the value in this variable?

Comment: you can see this product example. https://gilletts.com.au/stunning-68ct-natural-emerald-and-diamond-ring-f16200.. the Product Number: F16200 is the sku of this item.  I am trying to match any sku that starts with F to show the default value for the ring variable(in this rings instance the default is "I" (default value) else if the value M is in the list it will default to that else T  ect...

Comment: Ah, Its because of "f". If you want to ignore the case, use `stripos` instead. That ignores the case of the string you are trying to search.

Comment: ok so I that did not work but I changed the search ref to if (strpos($sku_code, 'f') == 0) (ie lower cap) and yes it works!  finally.. But is there a another way to ignore case as your 'stripos' did not work

Comment: You can either use `stripos` or lowercase `$sku_code` by doing `strtolower($sku_code)`.